# Android seekbar set value by default

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to show my seekbar value while open my activity without touch on seekbar.(Please refer the image below)[image]

Comment: do u have any code?

Comment: Put your code for more detail.

Comment: How to show this balloon icon with text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:progress` attribute in XML to set a default value to the `SeekBar` (as well as to `ProgressBar`)

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically set the ProgressBar value by doing:

```
progressBar.setProgress(storedValue);
```

Or via XML with the `progress` parameter

Comment: value is fine but I want to popup that balloon.

Comment: Your question is asking for the value: "I want to show my seekbar value". If you want the correct answer you must ask the right question. So rewrite your question or open a new one and show your ballon related code if you want us to be able to help you.